# Liapunov function (Energy function) for a nonlinear ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

I need to find a Energy function (Lyapunov function) for the next nonlinear coupled ODE system

$u'=-u+u^2v\\
v'=b-u^2v$

where $b\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$. The objective of this is to build a proper trapping region, but I can't fugure it out how to do it. I just don't know how to biuld a proper trapping region.

Then, once I got the trapping region, I'll apply the Poincaré-Bendixon theorem in order to prove that there's a limit cycle.

Comment: Are you really sure that you need Lyapunov function for this task? I'd rather say, that if you are going to use Poincare-Bendixson theorem, you should find an absorbing annulus that contains no equilibria. And this will prove that there's a periodic orbit inside that annulus. But I think that I've already told it you...

Comment: Do not post deliberate duplicates.

Comment: @Evgeny I'm still can't find that trapping region. I would love to show you mi calculations but there's nothing concrete. I can't explain what happen in the $v$ axis because all goes to infinity.